# Getting function to return array from tchar in win prog function

Tags: c++, winapi

So before diving into this its just that feeling that my knowledge of C(which is plain 0) will again prove painful when messing with winapi, my question is...

What is the most practical way to safely return function as TCHAR array, what i have is basically enumeration of listview items, i currently save them in the txt file and now i want to pass them all to array like

// SIMPLE VERSION I CURRENTLY HAVE

```
for (int nItem = 0; nItem < nMaxItems; nItem++) {

      // Get the name and position of a ListView item.


   for ( int subitem = 1; subitem < columns; subitem++)
   {

   ListView_GetItemText(hWndLV, nItem, subitem, szName, _countof(szName));


   wprintf(L"%s, ", szName);


   }  
   wprintf(L"%s", "\n");
 }
```

Its not a problem to solve the syntax and enumeration, its just that i want to make sure i do everything right when it comes to transfering this to array, it would be best if i could perhaps cast it to wstr type somehow, how would i go around that?

I need to return the array to use it with Autoit(which gives me worries as i am not sure if when i return tchar array it will work allright, so wstr should perhaps be better)

Answer (score 0):

you are using wprint which means you are either using unicode already or you are doming something really wrong.

first you should decide what you want to use: ANSI or UNICODE?

if you decide to use ANSI, you should replace your wprintf calls with printf calls like so:
printf("%s, ", szName);
printf("\n");

if you want to use unicode you should do it like this:
include wchar.h in your cpp file(s)

'wchar_t szName[200]; // or wszName if you want to be consistent on naming

ListView_GetItemTextW(hWndLV, nItem, subitem, szName, _countof(szName)); // note the W which means unicode explicitly

wprintf( L"\n"); // or wprintf(L"%s", L"\n"); if you insist on using %s'

Comment: and if you want to be able to target both use TCHAR in a systematic way

Comment: he could also use TCHAR to support both but I don't think that he is quite there yet.